# How to load a mysql array into an array without loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

Simple question. lets say I run the following:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
```

How can I load the mysql results array into a PHP array without doing a while loop? Example:

```
$mysql_results = array();
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$mysql_results = mysql_load_all_results_into_array($results);
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such way...If it were You'd probably know of it... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `mysql_` library does not offer a method to "fetch all" rows without looping through the results-object using `mysql_fetch_row()` (or similar).

You can, however, update your code to use the [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) library which contains a method named [`mysqli_result::fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to perform the task you desire. Alternatively, you could update to use [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) which contains a similar method named [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

As the `mysql_` methods are being deprecated, updating to `mysqli` (or `PDO`) is the recommended way to go regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with mysql. You have to loop. You can do that with [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQLi extension please :

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 0):

use: 
`$values = mysql_fetch_array($results);`
 but do check for success of your operation.... thus: 
`while ($values = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $msg = "Array gotten successfully.";
 }`